# How to click on button on each 3 mins without reset on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a popup box that i need to show on each 3 minutes of difference but it should not reset on page refresh.

i have used this script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        function myfunc(){
            $('#donate').click();
            $('#myModal').modal();
        }

        myfunc();

        setInterval( function(){ myfunc(); } , 30000 );  
    });
```

but i do not want it to run on page load it should be run in 3 minute interval. Any help will be appreciated..Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***it should not reset on page refresh*** normally, page refreshnig will reset many things. Unless you keep the values somewhere, even passing the values to the server (on loading new page) then server-side will send those values back in the new page.

Comment: so what should i do to set the value so that it will only work on time interval not reset on page load..will you please help me to find out the solution..

Comment: in fact I don't still understand your problem, you said you did not want the `myfunc()` to run on page load? of course when you page's loading has been done, all the code in `.ready(...)` will run. Isn't that what you want? Or you want the `myfunc()` to be delayed about 3 minutes after the page's loading done?

Comment: no dear i do not want it to run after page load first time it should be run then after 3 minutes it should be run and on each 3 minute difference it should be run should not affected by the page load time should not get reset..?

Comment: it is like advertisement popup that should display only on each min not get affected by the page reload..